# How to make cursor pointer on mouse hover only on a particular PieChart slice?

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I'm working on a `PieChart` of `HighChart` to show my user count status.

In the below chart, when I hover on the red color chart slice, then the `cursor: pointer` needs to enable.

If I hover on the green color chart slice, then I need to disable the `cursor` totally or set `cursor: default`.

Can anyone help me to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On a load event you need to set point's cursor to pointer.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
     type: 'pie',
     events: {
       load: function () {
         this.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
           cursor: 'pointer'
         });
       }
     }
   },
    series: [{
        data: [90, 10]
    }]
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwwsz2kz/

Comment: But I already tried this one "function(chart)
                            {
          $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,point)
                                {
                                    if(point.options.cursorEnabled)
                                        { 
                                            point.graphic.attr({cursor:'pointer'});
                                        }
                                });
                           });"    this one also working...